# Properties of starch in packaged pudding

Tags: organic-chemistry, home-experiment, viscosity

I had a mug of packaged pudding. The top layer of the pudding was of typical pudding consistency, while the bottom was more runny. What could have caused this?

Comment: The top layer is usually a solid elastic film. You mean the top half, or third or so, right?

Comment: yes I mean the top third @Karl

Answer (score 1):

Starch makes a glue or a paste with water. Humidity from the air may be sufficient to transform your starch into a glue. Water produces strong hydrogen bridges between starch molecules. This transforms a pile of independent starch molecules into a strong block of interconnected starch molecules.

Answer (score 1):

What you have witnessed is gelation coupled to phase separation. It depends on the composition of your pudding.

The process of preparing a starch gel begins with starch granules [swelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starch_gelatinization) and eventually dissolving with uptake of water. This initial step requires disrupting the structure of both amylopectin (more amorphous) and amylose (more crystalline) domains to form an aqueous solution of extended polymer chains. Melting of the granules occurs with heating. When the solution is cooled structure begins to reform, involving cross-linking (crystallization and entanglement) of the mixed chains, a process known as [retrogradation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrogradation_(starch)). As structure reforms water is pushed out of the gel, resulting in water-rich and water-depleted regions (phase separation). The less dense gel settles on top of the more dense polymer-depleted water-rich region.

For more information try a search for "phase separation gelation". The literature on the subject is vast and there are various mechanisms that can explain the phenomenon depending on the composition of the gel and other parameters such as temperature.